# How to Downloading file into CSV file using thingspeak api request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, api

I am struggling to get a downloaded cvs file on my local computer, i am using thingspeak cloud api to read data like date range. This range should be downloaed from the browser as file format either json or cvs file. I have followed this link from thingspeak forum to do this, still unable to get it right and using GET method on my ajax call request.https://nl.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/readfield.html

// Downloading file into zip file.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#download").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url:'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/feeds.csv?api_key=***&results=2',
        type:'GET',
        success:function(response){
          window.location = response;
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 3):

When your code makes a GET request to

`https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/feeds.csv?api_key=***&results=2`

The value of `response` will be the actual CSV data.

It seems like what you want to do is send the browser to this URL and take advantage of the browser's default behavior to download the response as a file for URLs that end in `.csv`

You can achieve this result with code like the following:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#download").click(function() {
      window.location.href = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/feeds.csv?api_key=***&results=2';
    });
  });
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the example, i end up getting the same behavior as to what you are indicating, its working fine with no problem what so ever.